# Why "Great Seattle Fire" and not "Great Fire of Seattle"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was reading this Wikipedia page about the [Great Fire of Valparaíso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Fire_of_Valpara%C3%ADso) and noticed that other major fire incidents was all named "Great Fire of CITY", except for Seattle.

[image]

Why's that?

Comment: There is no rule which decrees how calamities or disasters should be named. It is a matter of style. [One source](https://specialprojects.pressherald.com/portlands-great-fire/great-fires.html) lists the 1845 Great New York City Fire, the 1871 Great Chicago Fire, and the 1901 Boston Conflagration.

Comment: There is some suggestion that this is a difference between British/Global English and American usage - all of the examples @MichaelHarvey  has given are also from USA.

Comment: @MikeBrockington https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Sheffield_Flood